# In a maximal planar graph, are two consecutive neighbors of a vertex necessarily adjacent?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

If we pick a vertex $v$ and two consecutive neighbors of it, $u_1$ and $u_2$, are we sure that $(u_i, u_{i+1}) \in E$? Note: by consecutive I mean in a planar embedding; otherwise any two neighbors can be consecutive.

My intuition is that if $(u_1, u_2) \notin E$, you can add an edge by going from $u_1$ to $v$ and then to $u_2$, thus violating the maximality property that we assumed:

[image: adding an edge between u1 and u2]

This new edge is not going to intersect any edge incident to $v$ -- otherwise $u_1$ and $u_2$ are not consecutive neighbors; but can it intersect with other edges?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a purely mathematical question with no computational content.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. A counter example is $K_5-e$, i.e., removing any edge from a clique of five vertices.

Comment: Care to point out? I have a drawing of $K_5 - e$ here: http://imgur.com/rodfaC0

Comment: Maybe you are not using a planar embedding of $K_5 - e$? I have clarified my question so that the neighbors have to consecutive in a planar embedding.